# pdfmake rowspan and pagination issues

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmake

When using rowspan to merge cells, if the table spans pages, the merged cells on the second page do not display content. Is there a way to display the content?

[image]

Displaying red words is the effect I want.

[image]

and this is my code:

```
{
    table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: ['*', '*', '*', 55, 50, 70],
        body: [ ... ]
    }
}
```